# How to calculate percentage of column using pandas pivot_table()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I am attempting to get the frequency of objects per version expressed as a percentage.

Input `dfsof = pd.read_clipboard()`

```
file     version     object
path1    1.0         name
path1    1.0         session
path1    1.0         sequence
path2    2.01        name
path2    2.01        session
path2    2.01        sequence
path3    2.01        name
path3    2.01        session
path3    2.01        earthworm
```

Using the following, I am able to get frequency of each `file`.

`dfsof.pivot_table(index=['object'], values=['file'], columns=['version'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0, margins=True)`

```
             file
version      1.0    2.01    All
object          
 earthworm   0      1       1
 name        1      2       3
 sequence    1      1       2
 session     1      2       3
All          3      6       9
```

I want to divide each count per object/version by the total number of distinct files for that version. Using the expected return table as an example, earthworms shows up in the input only once for `version 2.01`, so I expect 0% for `version 1.0` and 50% for `version 2.01` since only one of the files has that value.

Using `dfsof.groupby('version')['file'].nunique()` returns the frequency of files per version, which is the denominator for each of object/version in the table above. What I am struggling with is how to apply the denominator values to the pivot_table. I have seen examples of this using grand totals and subtotals but I can't seem to find nor figure out how to divide by the unique number of files per version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
version
1.00    1
2.01    2
```

Expected return

```
             path
version      1.0    2.01    All
object          
 earthworm   0%     50%     1
 name        100%   100%    3
 sequence    100%   50%     2
 session     100%   100%    3
All          3      6       9
```

Comment: `df.pivot_table('object', 'file', 'version', normalize='index')`

Comment: Could it be as simple as `a / a.max()`? Assuming `a = dfsof.pivot_table(index=['object'], values=['file'], columns=['version'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0, margins=True)`

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't read the expected output carefully. You would need to worry about the `All` column/row in `a` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to aggregate as `'nunique'`, then perform some recomputation:

```
# aggregate using nunique
out = dfsof.pivot_table(index=['object'], values=['file'], columns=['version'],
                        aggfunc='nunique', fill_value=0, margins=True)

# compute and save sum of nunique
All = out.iloc[:-1].sum()
# update values as percentage
out.update(out.iloc[:-1, :-1].div(out.iloc[-1, :-1]).mul(100))

# assign sum of nunique
out.loc['All'] = All

print(out)
```

Output:

```
            file           
version      1.0   2.01 All
object                     
earthworm    0.0   50.0   1
name       100.0  100.0   3
sequence   100.0   50.0   2
session    100.0  100.0   3
All          3.0    6.0   9
```